# Recover data from within children with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase

can anybody help me? I'm having a problem similar to the previous post. I'm just not getting the child object. I have tried in several ways the most basic and logical would be: newPost.musician.statusbatera

Follows a chrome debug print: --Screen Shot--

[image: Screen Shot]

I'm not getting it because of the key generated automatically by firebase as the print in attached.

My code:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      var newPost = snapshot.val();
      console.log("Musician: " + newPost.musician.statusbatera);
});
```

Comment: Screenshots are generally unhelpful. A bulleted list of values would be more beneficial in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the autogenerated key using `Object.keys`, then you can assign the object you need:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var newPost = snapshot.val();
  keys = Object.keys(newPost.musician)
  console.log("Musician: " + newPost.musician[keys[0]].statusbatera);
});
```

in theory, there should be only one value in `keys`...

Comment: Thank you, Solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to iterate through `musician`'s list, if so, give this a try :-

```
for(var i = 0; i <= newPost.musician.lenght; i++) {
 console.log("Musician: " + newPost.musician[i].statusbatera);
}
```

Comment: The solution from the previous post solved my problem, the solution was to get the keys, When I try to get the size it is undefined, thank you very much for you help.